# How to parse Data from server? App getting crash on read of data from dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift

Here is my JSON data which I am getting from server.

```
{
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "resultcode": "000",
  "balance": "-32020",
  "available": "-32020",
  "reserved": 0
}
```

When I am trying to parse these JSON data, App crashed and throws `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1a17dab60) to 'NSString' (0x1a17e5798).`

I know the issue is about data type. But when I get Positive value for `reserved` key in above JSON data, it shows string value in JSON data, but when i get Negative value of `reserved` key, it return `Numeric` data type.

Here is the code Which i am reading data.

```
self.response?.objectForKey("reserved")  as! NSString
```

So How to deal with this kind of issue?

Comment: please update your method that you store this response

Comment: Please update code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse data using if let statements. Check below

```
if let reservedNum = JSON["reserved"] as? Double {
  print(reservedNum)
} else if let reservedString = JSON["reserved"] as? String {
  print(reservedString)
} else {
  print("Error Parsing Data") 
}    

if let safeResult = JSON["result"] as? String {
   print(safeResult)
}
```

And same for the rest and handle the response in a Modal.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
var reserved:Double?
if let reserved_string=response.value(forKey: "reserved") as? NSString{
    reserved=reserved_string.integerValue
}
if let reserved_float=response.value(forKey: "reserved") as? Double{
     reserved=reserved_float
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because in your json response , reserved key is NSCFNumber type so you can't directly force wrap this into NSString so use this way :

```
if let mReserved = self.response?.objectForKey("reserved")  as? Int {
  print(mReserved)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check what kind of data type is with Optional.

```
if self.response?.objectForKey("reserved")  as? NSString{
 //Do something with NSString
}else if self.response?.objectForKey("reserved")  as? NSNumber{
 //Do something with NSNumber
}else {
print("Error") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
let reservedStr = String(response.value(forKey: "reserved") as! Double)
```